Получить id дубликатов кроме самого последнего
Нужно найти записи с полем entity_types_id, значение которого повторяется более 1 раза. Далее, нужно получить id этих строк, кроме самой последней по id
Таблица:
subtask_templates, поля: id, entity_types_id, value
Написал запрос на поиск дубликатов:
SELECT entity_types_id FROM subtask_templates GROUP BY entity_types_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

И запрос на получение всех id согласно найденным entity_types_id
SELECT id, entity_types_id 
FROM subtask_templates
WHERE entity_types_id IN
      (SELECT entity_types_id FROM subtask_templates WHERE enabled = TRUE GROUP BY entity_types_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY id desc;

Но теперь не совсем понятно как убрать среди найденных записей записи с наибольшим id по каждому entity_types_id.



id
entity_types_id




106
200


104
200


63
200


34
99


32
99


9
99


3
99



В этой выборке нужно получить все строки, кроме id = 106 и id = 34

Можно добавить ещё один подзапрос. Например:
SELECT id, entity_types_id
FROM subtask_templates
WHERE entity_types_id IN
      (SELECT entity_types_id FROM subtask_templates WHERE enabled = TRUE GROUP BY entity_types_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
AND id NOT IN
      (SELECT MAX(id) FROM subtask_templates GROUP BY entity_types_id)
ORDER BY id DESC;


Спасибо! Решение подходит
